# HtmlUnit xpath getElement

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit

I am trying to create a web content crawler for a specific website

> http://v1000.vn/bang-xep-hang?ref=bang-xep-hang-1000-doanh-nghiep-dong-thue-thu-nhap-nhieu-nhat-2012

Shortly, my XPath to find the  link that change the page (using javascript) is not working which cause NullPointExecetion. I have tried to modify the XPath in various way but nothing worked.

Also, do I need to run any method to get the new page after the script run?

```
> package gimasys.webService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ThreadedRefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlLink;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Crawlv1000 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final WebCrawler wc = new WebCrawler();
        final PageCrawler pc = new PageCrawler();

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
        webClient.setRefreshHandler(new ThreadedRefreshHandler()); // This is to allow handling the page operation using threads else an exception will pop up
        try {
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://v1000.vn/bang-xep-hang?ref=bang-xep-hang-1000-doanh-nghiep-dong-thue-thu-nhap-nhieu-nhat-2012");
            HtmlAnchor link = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@href='javascript:loadRankingTable(3)']");
                        link.click();
                        System.out.println(page.getTextContent());

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
        wc.crawl("http://v1000.vn/bang-xep-hang?ref=bang-xep-hang-1000-doanh-nghiep-dong-thue-thu-nhap-nhieu-nhat-2012");

        for (String url:wc.urlList)
        {
            pc.crawl(url);
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Minh Nguyen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very small mistake done by you dear, semicolon mistake

```
HtmlAnchor link = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@href='javascript:loadRankingTable(3);']");
link.click();
```